# CONSULTA SQL ("SUM")

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ok, se que haciendo `SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM table_name` puedo obtener el total de una columna de mi tabla. Ejemplo:

Personas

NOMBRE---- SAUL,Eliz
APELLIDO--- ROMER,Guzman
EDAD------- 21,20

```
SELECT SUM(Edad) FROM Personas (El resultado sera 41)
```

¿pero como hago que me muestre los mismos datos (nombre,apellido y edad)y una columna extra con el total de las edades "41"?

hago la pregunta porque ya intente usando group by y el resultado no es el que deseo (La columna extra con el total)

lo que intente fue

```
SELECT NOMBRE,APELLIDO,SUM(Edad) 
FROM Personas
GROUP BY NOMBRE,APELLIDO
```

Comment: Y a que registro le asignarías la suma de todo? No es evidente, verdad? El agrupar te va a identificar esos subconjuntos para agrupar (nombres y apellidos diferentes) y para cada uno, suma. Si indicas cómo debería pintarse ese 41, tal vez obtengas una respuesta concreta

Comment: Que tal ErickG, bienvenido a S.O. ... Coincido totalmente con Alfabravo, si hablas de un formato que deseas obtener al menos seria bueno que nos lo muestres para poder ayudarte... Toma en cuenta que la suma de edades se va a dar según algún campo de agrupación, y también toma en cuenta que tienes nombres y apellidos distintos...

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la cláusula OVER con funciones de agregado y prescindir del GROUP BY

```
SELECT NOMBRE,APELLIDO,EDAD, SUM(EDAD) OVER() AS SUMAEDAD 
FROM Personas
```

O puedes usar una subconsulta de esta forma:

```
SELECT A.NOMBRE, A.APELLIDO, A.EDAD, B.SUMAEDAD
FROM Personas A, (SELECT SUM(EDAD) AS SUMAEDAD FROM PERSONAS) B
```

[image: En ambos casos el resultado es el mismo]